# Disadvantages of the Feistel network

Tags: encryption, algorithm-design, feistel-network

I have read about Feistel network and so far only advantages have been listed. Are there any disadvantages to the design? Please could you explain in fairly basic terms?

Comment: "... so far only advantages have been listed" - where? This isn't wikipedia, but...citation needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, what are we comparing Feistel networks to? The other major design paradigm is SPN: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution-permutation_network. In comparison to SPN, the cons are:

- Not a direct implementation of confusion and diffusion. Feistel networks have more structure that has no clear justification. (Some point to the security proof but if you assume a cryptographically secure round function, how wrong can things go? A better question is: "if your round function is weak, what does the Feistel network add?").
- Parallelism is about half of an equivalent SPN, which is a disadvantage for hardware implementations.

Comment: Can one say, that those are also the reasons why Feistel networks are hardly used any more these days?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a disadvantage because at least 3 rounds of the Feistel cipher are required. More details can be found here: [Is this a structural weakness of Feistel networks?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10555/is-this-a-structural-weakness-of-feistel-networks) - the computation cost will be higher.

Comment: This is close to a link-only answer to the same site. You should flesh it out a bit: compared to *what* is this a disadvantage?

Comment: generally all ciphers require multiple rounds, and usually quite a bit more than 3, I do not consider that a disadvantage unless there is no Feistel cipher that is as secure as some other cipher in the same range of performance

Comment: How is this a disadvantage? Three rounds is not very much.