# How to build disk encryption system using forward permutations like Gimli?

Tags: block-cipher, symmetric, pseudo-random-permutation, gimli

First of all, this is purely a thought experiment. The width of [Gimli](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/630.pdf) isn't even a power of two (384 bits), and secondary storage bus speeds aren't even worth using a high performance permutation like Gimli. So from a practical perspective, this is totally pointless.

But it's nonetheless an interesting one. And from it, I have three concrete questions that can be considered:

1. Can we build a tweakable bijective keyed permutation from just a pseudo-random forward permutation?
2. Is there a practical disk encryption system using only forward permutation?
3. How do we interpret the "new conventional wisdom" that "a permutation
   is a better unified primitive than a block cipher"?

Gimli paper can be [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/630.pdf).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I'm one of the authors of the said permutation.

1. Gimli does not aim to be used as a block cipher (in the traditional sense of it: $x \to (\sigma \circ K_{\mathit{add}})^{\mathit{nb}_{\mathit{rounds}}}$ with a block size of 384 bits or similar constructions); it is better to use it with a sponge construction such a [Monkey-Duplex/Monkey-Wrap](http://sponge.noekeon.org/) or [Farfalle](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/1188.pdf).
   An example of such a construction would be the design of [Ketje Sr](http://ketje.noekeon.org/).
2. No Idea.
3. > Imagine there's no blockciphers, it's easy if you try :-)
   >
   > ---
   >
   > Joan Daemen at FSE 2017 [[abstract]](https://www.nuee.nagoya-u.ac.jp/labs/tiwata/fse2017/Abstract_Joan_Daemen.pdf) [[slides]](https://www.nuee.nagoya-u.ac.jp/labs/tiwata/fse2017/slides/02-01.pdf)

   (I really advise you to have a look at the slides.)

   The idea is here is to have a unique permutation (Gimli? :D) on which you can derive the rest (hash functions, CPRNG, *etc.*). Sure you can use a Davies–Mayer or Even–Mansour with Merkle–Damgård construction to build a hash function from a blockcipher. But using a sponge construction is more *elegant* and efficient: you only have one code for the permutation and the design is easier to read (thus understand and verify).

Comment: Side note: It's always possible to turn any forward permutation into a generic block cipher using Feistel network.

Comment: @DannyNiu But performance isn't ideal anyway. https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/44007

Comment: Are intermediate state values per round published anywhere?

Comment: @back_seat_driver nope, we provide source code in C, Python and ASM.  You can compute the test vectors through the reference implementation.
We also provide the inversion of the non linear layer (cf appendix).

Comment: @Biv Are you going to revisit it, after Mike Hamburg's [cryptanalysis of 22.5 rounds of GIMLI](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/743.pdf)?

Comment: We don't know yet, but we are discussing about it internally (no public statement yet).

Comment: Thanks didn't know about the other source code, and it's almost like you know my habits.

Comment: it's not really a source code, but the formula for the recursive inversion (in order to prove the bijectivity).

Comment: The Gimli paper states “Gimli can easily be used to build high-security block ciphers, tweakable block ciphers...”, so what is the proposed mechanism the authors had in mind for doing so? An unbalanced Feistel network with Gimli as the round function would be terribly inefficient, wouldn't it?